# "00000000000000000000000000000" matches Regex "^[1-9]|0$"

Tags: c#, .net, regex

In .Net4.5, I find that the result of

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(
    "00000000000000000000000000000", "^[1-9]|0$")
```

is true.

The result I expect is false. I don't know why. Can you help me?

**Update**:
In the beginning, I was validating the regular expression `^-?[1-9]\d*|0$` which is used to match integer found on the internet and I find that the string with multiple `0` matches the regular expression.

Comment: Regex matches your input - there is an explanation on the right side.: http://regex101.com/r/fB9yK0/1

Comment: _Why_ do you expect it to be false?  What did you think the regex was trying to say?  Were you expecting it to behave like `^([1-9]|0)$` ?

Comment: @RayToal I think that `^[1-9]|0$` is equal to `^[0-9]$` before I know the answer.

Comment: @pwas Isn't that PCRE when OP is asking about .NET regex?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The issue is the alternator's binding behavior. By default (i.e. without using grouping), an expression containing an alternator (`|`) will match either the value to the left of the alternator, or the value to the right.

So in your expression, you're matching either one of these:

- `^[1-9]`
- `0$`

Your call to the `IsMatch` method returns `true` because the second of those two option matches the string `00000000000000000000000000000`.

To restrict the alternator's binding to a specific part of your expression, you need to group using parentheses, as follows:

```
^([1-9]|0)$
```

---

Putting all this together, a strict expression to validate integers, disallowing leading zeroes and negative zero, could look like this:

```
^(-?[1-9][0-9]*|0)$
```

Comment: To expand on that you need to add parentheses `()` around the parts you want to OR on: `^([1-9]|0)$` or just `^[0-9]$`

Comment: @Rhumborl Yup indeed. The actual goal was not really clear from the question, but I'll update my answer to reflect your comment.

Comment: indeed, I _assume_ that is what is required